# php stored procedure adding error

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I want to add data to my table with stored procedure, but I have this error:

> Gönder
>   Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Teknoloji,V,,1)' at line 1' in C:\xampp\htdocs\berat\isyerikayit.php:142 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\berat\isyerikayit.php(142): PDO->query('CALL isyerikayi...', 2) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\berat\isyerikayit.php on line 142

```
 <?php
      if (isset($_POST['gonder']))
     {
        $adi =  $_POST["adi"];
        $calismaturu =  $_POST["calismaturu"];
        $iscigucu =  $_POST["iscigucu"];
        $hizmetturu =  $_POST["hizmetturu"];
        $butce =  $_POST["butce"];
        if($calismaturu == 'V')
            {
                $sorgu= $db->query("CALL isyerikayitV($adi,$calismaturu,$iscigucu,$hizmetturu)",PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                echo '<script>alert("Hizmet Veren Firma Eklendi.");</script>';
            }
        else
            {
                $sorgu= $db->query("CALL isyerikayitE($adi,$calismaturu,$butce)",PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                echo '<script>alert("Hizmet Edilen Firma Eklendi.");</script>';
            }


     }
     ?>
```

My `isyerikayitE()` and `isyerikayitV` procedures are 7.

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `$iscigucu` is empty:

"that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Teknoloji,V,,1)'"

And all your string variables are missing the quotes:

A quick solution is to do:

```
$iscigucu =  empty($_POST["iscigucu"]) ? "''" : "'".$_POST["iscigucu"]."'";
```

for each one of them.

or

```
$iscigucu = "'".$iscigucu."'"
```

But the right way to solve this is to use prepared statements:

```
$call = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, 'CALL test_proc(?, ?, ?, ?)');
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($call, 'ssss', $adi,$calismaturu,$iscigucu,$hizmetturu);
mysqli_stmt_execute($call);
```

Take a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php